# Integration by substitution: use of appropriate substitutions with roots of even index

Tags: integration, soft-question, education, substitution

I have the following integrals
$$\int x\sqrt{x-1}\, dx, \quad \text{and} \quad \int \sqrt{e^x-1}\,dx$$
I am not interested in solving integrals but rather in a consideration that I have thought when I have solved the integrals to my high school students. I generally put the positions in such a way that there is no double sign. In other words I would place in the first case $x-1=t$ and in the second case $e^x-1=t$. I have found that in the adopted textbook, in the first case, the position is adopted instead is:
$$x-1=t^2$$
In the second case however I can use for analogy ($e^x-1=t^2$) It is true that $x-1>0$, and $t^2>0$, but if $$x-1=t^2 \implies t=\pm \sqrt{x-1}$$

> Why would I choose the $+$ sign instead of the minus sign when I operate substitutions under square root? Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer will be the same regardless of whether you choose the $+$ or $-$ sign.

Let's say you want to integrate $\int \sqrt{f(x)} \, dx$. We can write $t^2 = f(x) \implies t = \pm \sqrt{f(x)} \implies \pm t = \sqrt{f(x)}$.

Case $1$: You choose $t = \sqrt{f(x)}$.
$$\frac{dt}{dx} = g(t) \implies dx = \frac{dt}{g(t)}$$
$$\therefore \int \sqrt{f(x)} \, dx = \int t \, \frac{dt}{g(t)}$$

Case $2$: You choose $-t = \sqrt{f(x)} \implies t = -\sqrt{f(x)} $
$$\frac{dt}{dx} = -g(t) \implies dx = -\frac{dt}{g(t)}$$
$$\therefore \int \sqrt{f(x)} \, dx = \int -t \cdot \left(\, -\frac{dt}{g(t)} \right)= \int t \, \frac{dt}{g(t)}$$

As demonstrated, in both cases, you get the same result.

Comment: The important thing is just that you pick one or the other. It is easy to mess this up with something like $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx$, which if you are not careful can end up being incorrectly evaluated as 0.

Answer (score 3):

If you take $t = -\sqrt{x-1}$ (and therefore $-t = \sqrt{x-1}$ for when you make the substitution) then:

$$\frac{dt}{dx} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}},$$

$$dx = -2\sqrt{x-1}dt.$$

But notice when you substitute this back in, the minus signs cancel out, so you can proceed as normal.